# Mongoose - can't update property values in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here are the Schemas

```
export const publicTaskSchema = new Schema({
  task: { required: true, type: String },
  user: {   
    _user: { type: String, required: true },
    userName: { type: String, required: true },
   },
  likes: {
    users: [{ 
      _user: { type: String, required: true },
      userName: { type: String, required: true },
     }], 
   },
  comments: [{ 
    user: { 
      _user: { type: String, required: true },
      userName: { type: String, required: true },
     } 
   }],
});

export const publicTaskListSchema = new Schema({
  tasks: { required: true, type: [publicTaskSchema], default: null },
  totalTasks: { required: true, type: Number, default: 0 },
});
```

All I want to do is update the properties inside of the nested arrays.

For this I am trying to use positional operators with array filters to update all tasks that meet the requirements.

```
        const updated = await PublicTaskList.updateMany<PublicTaskListType>(
          {},
          {
            $set: {
              "tasks.$[].comments.$[user].userName": req.user.profile?.userName,
            },
          },
          { arrayFilters: [{ "user.user._user": req.user._user }], new: true }
        ).exec();
```

All I get is this as response

> { acknowledged: false }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were missing an extra `user` on this line:

```js
"tasks.$[].comments.$[user].user.userName"
```

For clarity I have changed your `user` positional identifier to `element` like this:

```js
const updated = await PublicTaskList.updateMany<PublicTaskListType>(
    {},
    {
        $set: {
            "tasks.$[].comments.$[element].user.userName": req.user.profile?.userName
        }
    },
    { 
        arrayFilters: [
            { 
                "element.user._user": req.user._user 
            }
        ]
    }
).exec();
```

Also, I've removed `new:true` as this is not a valid option for mongoose `Model.updateMany()`.

Comment: Oh my god thanks so much man. I've been stuck on this for HOURS. I thought I was accessing the element with the current array filter but didn't realize I had to drill down further. Thanks so much!

Comment: @userWantsToCode you're welcome. When doing array filters I like to put an obscure name or something like `var` or `element` as the identifier so that it's obvious it's not part of the the object.

Comment: Yeah man I'm going to need that. I just wasted like 7-8 hour  nonstop on this.  Thanks again :)